# Change textarea value using Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, field-update, long-text-area

I'm using a JQuery to change a textarea input value when a picklist is selected...i can see the value is changed in the screen when i select an item in the picklist but when saving the new value is not updated. I'm trying to update the textarea field without passing the control to the controller and just by handling within JQ.

Below the function called when a picklist is selected (onChange event). any value other than 'SEMQ' is selected from the piclist then 'VICAR' need to be updated. So i'm able this in the UI but after saving when i view the opportunity i see the old value retained

```
    VAR dat;
    function setPjCode(input){
    var inp = input.value; 
    dat = jQuery( '[id$=oprpcd]' ).val();
    if (inp == 'SEMQ') {
        jQuery( '[id$=oprpcd]' ).val(dat);
        jQuery( '[id$=oprpcd]' ).prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else{
        jQuery( '[id$=oprpcd]' ).val('VICAR');
        jQuery( '[id$=oprpcd]' ).prop('disabled', true); 
    }
   }
```

Picklist field

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Opportunity.New_Additional__c}" onChange="setPjCode(this)" id="oprnewext" required="true"/>
```

text area field:

```
<apex:inputTextarea value="{!Opportunity.PCode__c}" id="oprpcd" style="width:250px"/>
```

Comment: I am confused. You say you are trying to set the value yet the ID of the input field you show is not the id of the element you are setting. Also, please show the code from the pick list calling the function. In addition, why are you calling the function when the text area is changed? What you posted does not seem to match what you are saying

Comment: Ads far as saving, show the code / vf page part where you are doing that? Is the value changing on the UI but not passed to the DB or is the value in the UI not changing....

Comment: hi eric , the value is updated in vf ui but not after save in db...

Comment: Ok. So if your issue is that it is not being passed to the controller, don't you think that that part of your code would be relevant?? Everything you posted above is working per your statement. Unless you update your question to be more specific to your problem as well as the code that is related to the problem it will be closed for not including the minimum information needed to answer your question.

Comment: i have edited my post to give some info to it....any input to fix this issue pls?

Comment: Nothing more I can say here. You did not provide the code / markup that is doing the save so there is no way I can tell you were you are going wrong. Since the questions is about the data not saving the information you currently have is not enough to help you other than simply providing you with the complete code to do it (which it not what the site is for). Also, you cannot update the values in the database without passing it in some form to a controller or using the standard save method if it is a standardcontroller

Answer (score 2):

I created the below snippet and its working totally fine

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery,'scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')}"></script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputfield id="rtf" onChange="updateValue();" value="{!Account.pqr__c}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="save Account" action="{!save}"/>
    </apex:form>

    <script>

        function updateValue(){
           $("[id$='rtf']").val('<div><p>abc</p></abc>'); 
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thk u, i think i got the issue...i'm trying to set the textarea and making it disabled which causes the field not to be updated with the new value.